# Flink: Which watermark strategy is appropriate when union multi kafka source and merge them together?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am a newer of flink. I have five unlimited kafka source with different data schema. I want to reduce message then outer join all the kafka source with same key.
So I use union to combine them together and then use *ProcessWindowFunction* to convert them to a big object. Then send to downstream.
I have two question.

1. I think I found the data losing root cause. There always one kafka source watermark late then others. So it message will be dropped.
2. For duplicated message, I think it's related with windown size and union operator. It's not an issue for my logic.

```
        class CommonObj {

            var id: Long = 0
            var entityType: String? = null
            var timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val eventMetas: MutableList<EventMeta> = mutableListOf()

            var kafkaStreamValue1: KafkaStreamObj1? = null
            var kafkaStreamValue2: KafkaStreamObj2? = null
            var kafkaStreamValue3: KafkaStreamObj3? = null
            var kafkaStreamValue4: KafkaStreamObj4? = null

            fun buildSinkObj(): SinkObj = ....
        }
```

This is one of kafka source code. Other kafka source logic is very similar.

```
        val watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps<KafkaStreamObj1>()
            .withIdleness(Duration.ofMinutes(1))

        val sourceStream1 = env.fromSource(
            getKafkaStream1(params),
            watermarkStrategy,
            "Kafka Source 1"
        )

        val kafkaSource1 = sourceStream1
            .filter { it != null }
            .map {
                EventObj<KafkaStreamObj1>(
                    it.id.toString() + it.entity, //this is key
                    it,                           //obj
                    it.sequence,                  //timestamp
                    mutableListOf(EventMeta(it.transactionId, it.type, it.sequence, it.changed))
                )
            }
            .returns(TypeInformation.of(object : TypeHint<EventObj<KafkaStreamObj1>>() {}))
            .keyBy {
                it.key }
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(10000)))
            .reduce { v1, v2 ->
                if (v1.obj.sequence > v2.obj.sequence) {
                    v1.eventMetaList.addAll(v2.eventMetaList)
                    v1
                } else {
                    v2.eventMetaList.addAll(v1.eventMetaList)
                    v2
                }
            }
            .map {
                val commonObj = CommonObj()
                commonObj.id = it.obj.id
                commonObj.entityType = it.obj.entity
                commonObj.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
                commonObj.eventMetas.addAll(it.eventMetaList)
                commonObj.kafkaStreamValue1 = it.obj.entity
                commonObj
            }
            .returns(TypeInformation.of(object : TypeHint<CommonObj>() {}))
        return kafkaSource1
```

This union code

```
        kafkaStream1.union(kafkaStream2,kafkaStream3,kafkaStream4,kafkaStream5)
            .keyBy(keySelector)
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(10000)))
            .process(EventProcessFunction(params))
            .sinkTo(kafkaSink())
```

The EventProcessFunction will merge all the kafka source message to a CommonObj. It will reduce duplicate by key and timestamp.

I deleted some sensitive information.

=======================================================

Update 2023-12-11

I did some optimization. But there always one kafka source have backpressure and it's watermark is late then the union watermark. So the late message will be dropped.
As my understanding, union will use the smaller watermark of all the union source. Although set withIdleness for 1 minute, but the late source have traffic and is being consumed.
Why the union watermark is advanced by not the smaller watermark?

================================================================

Update 2023-12-14

Thanks kkrugler suggestion.
Actually, I don't care if the event is late. If it's late, just process it as usual.
So I will try to use processing time windown.

Currently, I have changed to use processing time window and no watermark. When I use TumblingProcessingTimeWindows, there are high backpressure on all kafka source. And checkpoint will timeout after 10m. How can I adjust the backpressure and checkpoint issue?

I have tried to adjust the window size 10-30s. But the issue is going on.

Comment: You have three different questions here - how to combine streams coming from Kafka topics with different schemas, how watermarks should work with different Kafka topics, and how to do deduplication. I would split them up into separate SO questions...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the primary question about watermarking, you should be applying watermark strategies to each Kafka source, via the (newer) `StreamExecutionEnvironment.fromSource()` method, then combine the streams.

Comment: Thanks your answer.
Why need different watermark strategies to each Kafka source?
Currently, I use the same  forMonotonousTimestamps

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had Kafka topics with different event time characteristics. If you know that all topics contain messages with increasing timestamps, AND you provide the watermark strategy to the source via `.fromSource()`, then you can use `forMonotonousTimestamps` with all Kafka topics.

Comment: Hi kkrugler, I think it don't need watermark at all. Because I don't care the event sequence and if it's late. When event come in and process it as usual.
 As the CommonObj, have four events, every event only have one of the kafkaStreamValue. Then I want merge all the four events into one CommonObj. How can I aggregate a windown message into one object?

Comment: So you're saying you could use process time (versus event time), and thus never have any late events, right?

Comment: I don't care if event is late. If late, just process it as usual. Currently, I have changed to use processing time window and no watermark. When I use TumblingProcessingTimeWindows, there are high backpressure on all kafka source. And checkpoint will timeout after 10m. How can I adjust the backpressure and checkpoint issue?

Comment: Just to make sure we're clear here, with processing time there are no "late" events.

Comment: Looks like you've now got a different issue (high backpressure, checkpoint timeout). Please ask a new question about this, thanks.